# Spring MVC, Migrate @ExceptionHandler to HandlerExceptionResolver for a RESTful service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, content-type

### Background

I have an error message class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorMessage {
    private String message;

    public ErrorMessage() {
    }

    public ErrorMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setError(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

This class has been assigned as a return value to an @ExceptionHandler in my Spring MVC REST controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ResponseBody
ErrorMessage handleException(RuntimeException e) {
    return new ErrorMessage("something went wrong");
}
```

Whenever the client triggers a `RuntimeException` after issuing a request with `application/json` as a `Accept` header, it receives a response with the correct status code and a matching JSON body:

```
{"error":"something went wrong"}
```

Alternatively, an XML body is received if the `Accept` header is `application/xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<errorMessage><error>something went wrong</error></errorMessage>
```

### Problem

Now, I would like to generify this solution by implementing a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) instead so I don't have to copy / paste the `@ExceptionHandler` to every controller (or create a common "parent controller" that the other controllers can extend).

However, the [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.html#doResolveException%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Exception%29) method returns a `ModelAndView` and not my propriety `ErrorMessage`, so I tried the following:

```
public class RuntimeExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.addObject("error", "something went wrong");
            return mav;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When debugging, I can see that the `mav.addObject()` method is called. The response on the client side has the expected status code, but the content type is `text/html` with html in the body, rather than the JSON or XLM content that was specified by the `Accept` header in the original request.

(Side note, the actual exception, response code and text message in the example above is not important, they just serve as simple example.)

Spring version: 3.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spent some time investigating the matter and I have written a [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/09/23/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-ii/) in which I present a solution to the problem.

Update: If you are using Spring 3.2, you can take advantage of the [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) annotation. More details can be found in my [second blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2013/02/03/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-iii/).

Answer (score 4):

To get `@ExceptionHandler`s to use content negotiation, the [`AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.html) has a [`setMessageConverters()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.html#setMessageConverters%28org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter%5B%5D%29) method which must be provided with the message converters, e.g.:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xmlConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But since you're using a custom method, you'll probably have to implement this functionality yourself. The simplest way is probably to `Ctrl-C Ctrl-V` from the [`AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java?format=ok), specifically the `handleResponseBody()` method.

Comment: By using [@EnableWebMvc or <mvc:annotation-driven />](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) and adding Jackson on the classpath, you don't need to configure the message converters. Spring  will give you both JSON, XML (and a few other converters) by default. I will take a closer look at the source code of the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: Jaha; I never got content negotiation working with `@ExceptionHandler`s without specifying the converters explicitly, but that might depend on another aspect of my config. Unfortunately, `setMessageConverters()` doesn't seem to be part of an interface so it's unlikely the message converters will be injected automatically. Also, hi from Malmö.